# Comparison variable and field in DB

Tags: php, laravel

I have User table, Role Table with relationship `belongsTo`
I create policy for method create post and check for role:

```
public function hasAdminRole(): bool
{
    return $this->isAdmin() || $this->isSuperAdmin();
}
```

I have function isAdmin:

```
public function isAdmin() {
    if($this->role->id == '2') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this fucntion I have a problem, function always return true.

Comment: __Which__ function returs true?

Comment: Can you show the code for `$this->isSuperAdmin()`?

Comment: If you are checking if $this->role->id equal integer 2, make 2 without single quotes..

if($this->role->id == 2) {
            return true;
        }